# Строка с min и цветом для неё

Tags: excel

Здраствуйте, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать чтобы подсвечивалася строка из найменьшим число?, потипу чтобы в поле с минимальным числом снизу показывалося и выделало цветом строку от кудова он его взял.
извените не умею правельно формулировать вопросы и особо. Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Через условное форматирование.